# Unable to change CrystalReports logging level in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, crystal-reports, log4j

I have a Spring boot (Java) application that generates PDF reports using .rpt (Crystal Reports) files. I occasionally get these cryptic error messages before my application outputs a 0 byte PDF file:

```
ERROR com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter -  detected an exception: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:424)
ArrayList.java:424
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
ArrayList.java:437
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.FormattedObjectContainer.i(SourceFile:113)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.ah.a(SourceFile:131)
```

This only happens sometimes (and other times, I get a completely normal PDF file)

I know that I can get debug output from crystal reports that will help direct me to the cause of the problem, but I am unable to set the logging level of the Crystal Report libraries.

I have tried adding this to my `application.properties`

```
logging.level.com.crystaldecisions.=DEBUG
logging.level.com.crystaldecisions12.=DEBUG
logging.level.com.businessobjects.=DEBUG
```

both with and without the extra `.` before the `=`

I have tried:

```
log4j.logger.com.businessobjects. = DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.businessobjects12. = DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.crystalreports. = DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.crystaldecisions12. = DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.crystaldecisions. = DEBUG
```

Without and success.

I have even tried adding this in my code:

```
System.setProperty("crystal.enterprise.trace.configuration","verbose");
```

and this:

```
org.apache.log4j.Level rootLevel = Logger.getRootLogger().getLevel();
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL);
```

without any success.

How do I enable debug or trace logging in Crystal Reports?